# Serialized array outputting as the number 1

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, output

I cannot figure out how to output results from an array that was sent with `serialize()`, through an`ajax` POST.

The code following this is what I have now. The number `1` is what outputs. If I remove the `print_r` from the variable, the array just outputs as the word `Array` and I get the array to string error.

I cannot figure out how to get the results of the array to output as the actual string.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<label class="drop-item">A<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type" class="drop-item-input" value="A"></label>
<label class="drop-item">B<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type" class="drop-item-input" value="B"></label>
<label class="drop-item">C<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type" class="drop-item-input" value="C"></label>
```

Acquiring the value in my php like:

```
$proposal_type = print_r($_POST['prop-type']);
```

Echoing the variable in an email like the following:

```
proposal inquiry for a ' . $proposal_type . '.
```

Expanded code:

```
$proposal_type = $_POST['prop-type'];
    $mail->Body    = '
    <div id="email-link-container" style="width:600px;height:auto;">
        <p>' . $proposal_company . '</p>
        <p>' . foreach($proposal_type as $key => $value){ echo $key.'=>'.$value; } . '</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting here the return value of `print_r` function,

```
$proposal_type = print_r($_POST['prop-type']);
```

If you want to just print array for debugging purposes do only `print_r($_POST['prop-type'])`, and if you want to iterate array and get values in variables one by one use foreach or for loop for that,

```
foreach($_POST['prop-type'] as $key => $value){
    echo $key.'=>'.$value;
}
```

You can't just print array with echo.

Edit:

If you want to echo specific value from array you can do,

```
echo $proposal_type[0];
echo $proposal_type[1];
```

Depends upon what value you want to access.

For your specific problem you can do,

```
$proposal_type = $_POST['prop-type'];
$mail->Body    = '
<div id="email-link-container" style="width:600px;height:auto;">
    <p>' . $proposal_company . '</p>';

foreach($proposal_type as $value){
   $mail->Body .= '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
}
```

Comment: How would I be able to then call the array later on in the page? As of now, I am just calling the variable. Am I able to do that with the `foreach` method you gave?

Comment: I am not getting you, but foreach will not going to change your array, it is just a loop you can use your array as many times as you want.

Comment: Then just do `$proposal_type = $_POST['prop-type']` without `print_r` I am assuming `$_POST['prop-type']` is an array.

Comment: You are echoing the `$proposal_type` instead you have to use `print_r` or `foreach` to show array content.

Comment: So, can I do this then? `$proposal_type = foreach($_POST['prop-type'] as $key => $value){
    echo $key.'=>'.$value;
}`

Comment: Sorry, I rarely use PHP, so I am really rusty.

Comment: No, you are getting me wrong, In any circumstances you can't just echo array this will not help you have to `foreach` on `foreach($proposal_type as $key => $value){ echo $key.'=>'.$value; }` later in your code.

Comment: And if you want to just echo specfic value from your array you can do `echo $proposal_type[0]`,`echo $proposal_type[1]` any value you want.

Comment: Put this in your question correctly because Comments became too long and I am not getting it in comments.

Comment: Code put into question.